# How to compare a text value in a list of sobjects?

Tags: apex, soql, sobject, list

The following gives me a list of texts which are customer numbers (CUST_NUM__c)

```
 List<SYSTEMS__c> lst_PartnersAcc = [SELECT CUST_NUM__c
                                             FROM SYSTEMS__c WHERE Account__c IN (Select  AccountId from AccountShare where ( UserOrGroupId IN : map_group OR  UserOrGroupId =:userId )AND RowCause IN ('Territory', 'TerritoryManual', 'TerritoryRule'))
                                             ];
```

I have 4 text fields in another custom object **orders__c**==> customer_1__c,customer_2__c,customer_3__c, customer_4__c.
I'm trying to find out if **lst_PartnersAcc ** contains 1 or more of the 4 text field. My Final Aim is to find a list of orders if any matches from the string in the list.

Following is what I tried...

**Attempt 1:**

```
Set<String> tempList = new Set<String>();
tempList.addAll(lst_PartnersAcc);
```

> Error: Compile Error: Incompatible argument type List for All method on Set

**Attempt 2:**

```
List<orders__c> orders = [select id,name from orders__c WHERE customer_1__c IN( SELECT CUST_NUM__c
                                             FROM SYSTEMS__c WHERE Account__c IN             
                                             (Select  AccountId from AccountShare where ( UserOrGroupId IN : map_group OR  UserOrGroupId =:userId )AND RowCause IN ('Territory', 'TerritoryManual', 'TerritoryRule')))
                                             ];
```

> Error: Compile Error: Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported

**Attempt 3**

```
List<SYSTEMS__c> lst_PartnersAcc = [SELECT CUST_NUM__c
                                             FROM SYSTEMS__c WHERE Account__c IN  (Select  AccountId from AccountShare where ( UserOrGroupId IN : map_group OR  UserOrGroupId =:userId )AND RowCause IN ('Territory', 'TerritoryManual', 'TerritoryRule'))];

List<gew_orders__c> orders = [select id,name from gew_orders__c WHERE  GEW_SAP_Bill_to__c IN: lst_PartnersAcc OR
                                    GEW_SAP_Payer__c IN: lst_PartnersAcc OR 
                                    GEW_SAP_Ship_To IN: lst_PartnersAcc OR
                                    GEW_SAP_Sold_to__c IN: lst_PartnersAcc];
```

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of SYSTEMS__c for column of type String

How should I proceed to compare 4 values to a list? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your attemp 1, your are trying to convert an sObject into a String. That's doesn't work. If you want to add your field into the Set you need to do convert one by one your field into a string with : String.valueOf(theRecord.TheField)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
List lst_PartnersAcc = [SELECT CUST_NUM__c
                                             FROM SYSTEMS__c WHERE Account__c IN (Select  AccountId from AccountShare where ( UserOrGroupId IN : map_group OR  UserOrGroupId =:userId )AND RowCause IN ('Territory', 'TerritoryManual', 'TerritoryRule'))
                                             ];
Set tempList = new Set();
for(Systems__c s : lst_PartnersAcc) {
    tempList.add(s.Cust_Num__c);
}
List orders = [select id,name from orders__c WHERE customer_1__c IN :tempList OR customer_2__c IN :tempList ETC...
                                             ];
```

Just needed to add the Customer Number to the set individually for each `Systems__c`.

Comment: Just a quick clarification. what would be the type of Set? shShould  it be Set <id>tempList = new Set<id>(); ?

Comment: If `Cust_Num__c` is a reference (lookup or master/detail) then the Set should be `Set<Id>`.  If it is just a text field, it should be `Set<String>`